# $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n a^\frac{2i}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{n}=?$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Solve definite integral by limit definition:

$$\int_{0}^2 a^x dx$$
$I \:have  \:\:\Delta x = \frac{2}{n}\:\:; \:\:f(c_i)=a^\frac{2i}{n}$

Now i have  :$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n a^\frac{2i}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{n}$$

Don't know how to handle it , need a bit help if possible

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: This is a geometric series.

Comment: write the summation in terms of the finite geometric series and let $n$ to infinity

Comment: @CSquared I don't really know about geometric series, if you could give me a visual help to this example

Comment: $1+a+a^2+a^3+...+a^n$ is called geometric series.

Comment: So what does this equals to  :$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n a^\frac{2i}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{n}$$

Answer (score 1):

For $r,c\in\mathbb{R}$ with $r$, we have that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}cr^{i-1}=\frac{c(1-r^n)}{1-r}\tag{1}$$

$r$ is typically called the common ratio and $c$ is just a constant.

I will assume that $|a|<1$, since no conditions were given. You want to get $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^{2i/n}$$ into the form of $(1)$. So for a fixed $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we perform some manipulations to get

(Edited the following lines as they were incorrect in the first attempt)

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^{2i/n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(a^{2/n}\right)^i=a^{2/n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(a^{2/n}\right)^{i-1}=a^{2/n}\frac{1-\left(a^{2/n}\right)^n}{1-a^{2/n}}$$

It should be easier to evaluate the integral, which is now just $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^{2/n}}{n}\cdot\frac{1-a^{2}}{1-a^{2/n}}$$